# Mysql Foreign key: yes or no

Tags: mysql, database

i'm just 3 stackoveflow questions old :) in working with php and mysql so this could be stupid question.

with my basic php and mysql skills and with help from this community i was able to make one small web based database of machines company i work in is servicing with statistik of what was done on particular machine and the info to what client it belongs.

now, while the code works fine, with digging more in php and mysql i'm trying to refine it a bit.

my current problem is foreignkey in mysql. Before mysql i was working a bit with MS Access 2003 and connecting tables is very important part of it and i just do not understand how to work with tables without it.

On another hand i see that foreign key is not something mysql designers always use.

I need help with understanding how table relations work if there is no foreign key. If i change a record in one table do i have to manually cascade through all related tables and change it?

exsample:

client has one or more facilities and facility has one or more machines.

in my case facility has a client_ID fk and machine has facility_ID fk. If machine is sold to another client - client2 in the facility2, all i have to do is change facility_ID to facility2_ID for that to reflect to client2 as well.

what is the best practice here?

Comment: There is no reason to not use foreign keys. The reason why so many MySQL "designers" don't use them is historical: MySQL did not support foreign keys for a long time and even today not all storage engines do (and sometimes developers are just too lazy to use them, because they suddenly need to think about in which order they apply inserts, updates or deletes)

Comment: read about `normalization` (1Normal Form, 2NF and 3NF). You will be able to appreciate the usefulness of foreign keys

Comment: thx @a_horse_with_no_name. the thing is, according to MySQL manual, foreign key requires InnoDB while MySQL prefers MyISAM for speed and i do not know what else. sounds to me that even MySQL saiz "do not use it". or i could be just paranoid :)

Comment: @arunmoezhi thx. i did read that. and i know why to use fk. my question is why not?

Comment: for instance in `data warehousing` you should avoid using foreign keys as this involves mostly reads. But in a real time application there will be lot of updates and normalization (using foreign keys) helps to manage the database efficiently

Comment: In newer MySQL versions InnoDB is (finally) the default storage engine. But data integrity was never an important thing for MySQL. They still don't have check constraints and their FK support is not really state-of-the-art either - even with InnoDB you can declare foreign keys that are not enforced (and its still missing deferrable constraints).